# Remove backslash instances from a file in Python

Tags: python, instance, backslash

Okay, this may sound like a stupid question, but I can't solve this problem...

I need remove all instances of backslash from downloaded file...  But,

```
output.replace("\","")
```

doesn't work. Python considers "\"," a string, rather than "\" one string and "" the other one.

How can I remove backslashes?

EDIT:
New problem...
Originally, downloaded file had to be processed, which I did using:

```
fn = "result_cache.txt"
f = open(fn)
output = []
for line in f:
    if content in line:
        output.append(line)
f.close()
f = open(fn, "w")
f.writelines(output)
f.close()
output=str(output)
#irrelevant stuff
with open("result_cache.txt", "wt") as out:
    out.write(output.replace("\\n","\n"))
```

Which worked okay, reducing file's content to only one line...
And finally ended with having this contents only:

```
Line of text\
Another line of text\
There\\\'s more text here\
Last line of text
```

I can't use the same thing again, because it would transform every line to a value in a list, leaving brackets and commas... So, I need to have:

```
out.write(output.replace("\\n","\n"))
out.write(output.replace("\\",""))
```

in the same line... How? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just escape the backslash with a backslash:

```
output.replace("\\","")
```

Comment: it replaces contents with [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='result_cache.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1250'>]

Comment: @Mirac7 This removes backslashes so it must be something else. What you just posted is an attempt to open a file

Comment: Can I do something like this?
output.replace(["\\n","\n"],["\\",""])

Comment: @Mirac7 This looks like a different question since I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to reopen a file after output.replace("\\n","\n") or else there is no effect, like output.replace("\\","") is not even executed...

Comment: And file is saved as a list, line by line, in a variable output... output.replace("\\n","\n") creates additional lines causing another saving to modify contents in undesired way...

Comment: @Mirac7 you need to add these details to your question when you ask it, it's too hard to discuss all this over comments.